# Issue with Connecting to Firebase Datastore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a list of users using the collection feature in firebase however, I am running into these errors.
[image: Errors when trying to submit data]
Here is the information that I am entering.

[image: Input field]

Here is my code.

```js
const Signup = () => {
   const [err, setErr] = useState(false);
   const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reload

      const displayName = e.target[0].value;
      const email = e.target[1].value;
      const password = e.target[2].value;
      const profilePic = e.target[3].files[0];

      try {
         const res = createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

         const storageRef = ref(storage, displayName);

         const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, profilePic);

         uploadTask.on(
            (error) => {
               setErr(true);
            },
            () => {
               getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(
                  async (downloadURL) => {
                     await updateProfile(res.user, {
                        displayName,
                        photoURL: downloadURL,
                     });

                     await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid), {
                        uid: res.user.uid,
                        displayName,
                        email,
                        photoURL: downloadURL,
                     });
                  }
               );
            }
         );
      } catch (err) {
         setErr(true);
      }
   };
```

Authentication works perfectly. I just have a problem creating a collection in the cloud firestore.

Comment: Check [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.uploadtask.md#uploadtaskon) for UploadTask.on() again. It looks like you've got your parameters in the wrong places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is an asynchronous call here:

```
const res = createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
```

So your `res` variable is a `Promise` and a promise doesn't have a `user` property that you call here:

```
await updateProfile(res.user, { // 
   displayName,
   photoURL: downloadURL,
});
```

Which is what then leads to the error message, as the Firebase SDK tries to read properties of the `undefined` value that you pass there.

My guess is that you want to `await` for the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` call to complete, so:

```
const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
```